# Bootstrap navbar error

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

When i started using bootstrap everything was working fine, The navbar was looking great etc. But then i found something. When i click on the home link in the bar it does it's job and it brings me to the homepage. But when i click for example contact. It brings me to the contact page but the homepage link is still lighted up. So basicaly the navigation bar says i'm still on the homepage when clearly i'm in the contact page.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap-3/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap-3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <title>Welcome to the homepage!</title>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <header class="navbar-inverse" role = "banner">
           <div class="container">
            <nav role="navigation">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Blahblahism</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                       <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                       <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  </form>
              </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </nav>
          </div>       
        </header>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see here :

```
<li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
```

That you have the class `active` added to the first li element (home here).
So in every pages you will see the Home item beeing selected.

What you have to do is adding the `active` class to your current page.

It can be done server side or client side depending your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Tou may remove the active class:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li **class="active"**><a href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

And your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error with Bootstrap as you need to change which menu item is "active" on each page.
To do this you need to add the active class to the list item element to highlight the correct link as active

```
 <li class="active">
```

So on the home page your code should be as you have above:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

and on the Contact page it should be as follows:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home </a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note: I have removed the sr-only span to make this solution easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

To light up an element as active in Bootstrap you need to add the `active` class to it:

In your case that means:

In homepage.html:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

In contact.html:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

More about the active class can be found in [Bootstrap's Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-active)